# How to prove this language is not context-free language by pumping lemma?

Tags: automata

Could I get help to prove that the language $\{a^i b^j c^k \mid i>j>k\ge 0\}$ is not context free language by using pumping lemma?

Comment: Have you considered any word that might not be able to be pumped? If yes, please edit the question to demonstrate your idea.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?